# .bat file to shell conversion to pass variable between Jenkins build step and post build step

Tags: shell, powershell, batch-file, jenkins

In my Jenkins post build email (using extended email plugin), I want to use a variable identified in a build step (windows batch) using the EnvInject plugin. The plugin requires a properties file to be created using a shell script.  I am having difficulties converting the following batch lines to shell:

```
svn log --limit 1 > Change_Request.txt

set "ChangeRequest="
for /f "skip=3 delims=" %%i in (Change_Request.txt) do if not defined ChangeRequest set "ChangeRequest=%%i"

echo ChangeRequest=%ChangeRequest% > export.properties
```

Comment: Is shell to be meant powershell?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "shell", directly in your question. How does PowerShell come into play?

Answer (score 2):

The situation:  There is a Jenkins plugin named EnvInject that allows variables to be passed from a build step to a post build step. The variable was not being passed between the steps.

Perceived issue at the time: After reading the error log message and instructions on using the plugin, I thought the plugin only worked with a shell script.

Real issue: I was trying to read the properties file from a different location than where it was written.

Solution:  Initially resolved by using a shell script to write the variable to a properties file:

```
echo ChangeRequest=$(svn log --limit 1|sed '4q;d')>export.properties
```

This resolved the issue as it created the properties file in the expected location.

But if I had properly identified the issue, it could have been resolved in the initial batch script.

When updating the Jenkins job to pass a second variable, I realized the real reason my initial effort failed.  I updated my first batch script to pass the variables to a properties file, in the expected location.  I ran my svn command from the repository directory, then returned to my job's workspace directory to write the properties file.

```
svn log --limit 1 > ..\..\..\Change_Request.txt

for /f "skip=3 delims=" %%i in (..\..\..\Change_Request.txt) do if not defined >ChangeRequest set ChangeRequest=%%i

for /f "delims=: tokens=1,2" %%a in ('svn info %Repository_URL%') do (
  if "%%a"=="Revision" (
set /a RevisionNumber=%%b
  )
)

CD D:\Jenkins\workspace\JOB_Folder\

echo ChangeRequest=%ChangeRequest% > export.properties

echo RevisionNumber=%RevisionNumber% >> export.properties
```

Comment: There is an error in the first for with the output redirection symbol. Should be `if not defined ChangeRequest set ChangeRequest=%%i`

Answer (score 1):

Having no svn I can't test this, but it might work.
Coming from windows I'm quite new to shell/bash.

First version quite simmilar:

```
svn log --limit 1 > Change_Request.txt
ChangeRequest=$(sed '4q;d' Change_Request.txt)
echo ChangeRequest=$ChangeRequest>export.properties
```

---

Shorter no var:

```
svn log --limit 1 > Change_Request.txt
echo ChangeRequest=$(sed '2q;d' Change_Request.txt)>export.properties
```

---

Shortest no intermediate file (maybe required)

```
echo ChangeRequest=$(svn log --limit 1|sed '4q;d')>export.properties
```

---

**PowerShell variant**

```
svn log --limit 1 > Change_Request.txt
"ChangeRequest=$((gc Change_Request.txt)[4])" > export.properties
```

Comment: Thanks LotPings.  Your one line solution answered my question :

    echo ChangeRequest=$(svn log --limit 1|sed '4q;d')>export.properties

Comment: Wow, one month delay. It would be nice if you vote up and/or accept my answer in shorter time ;-)

Comment: Sorry for the long delay.  Once it worked I just kept jumping to the next requirement and then the next.  I will respond quicker next time.

Comment: You really should read [why-vote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and [whats-reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)